# Android - How to display BarGraph in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, graph

is it possible to display a `Bar Graph` in android?, like displaying two sets of data using a `Bar Graph`.
is there any libraries for this?, hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: Yes why not. Search for MPChart library

Comment: use https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar 
Thank you both, can you teach me how to import library in android studio?. sorry i don't usually visited github

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes thank you

Comment: @Lynerd: i think you got answer below hoe to use in android studio. here is detailed documentation of MPAndroidChart Lib https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it possible to display a Bar Graph in android?

Yes, it is possible.

> like displaying two sets of data using a Bar Graph. is there any
>   libraries for this?

Yes, use MPAndroidChart library for Bar Graph.

check link of [MPAndroidChart.](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

You can generate BarGraph as in below image

[image]

[image]

---

**How to use this library in Android Studio:**

**Add the following to your build.gradle:**

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: any tutorials or examples guys do you have?, about using Bar graph

Comment: Download whole code from given link of github and it has all sample examples available in it @Lynerd