# customize bars of the barchart in Achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I have been trying to create a bar chart in achartengine and I want the chart to look like this

[image]
The bars should have a background color. Is it possible to get this in achartengine?
Thanks In advance.

Comment: please provide screen of your chart

Comment: please Click on the image in the question

Comment: provided! done.

Comment: why dont you use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238770/android-how-to-display-bargraph-in-android/35238951#35238951

Comment: @Amit Vaghela the best way is to make your own chart. A couple of days ago I tried to understand how this damn custom library worked. With no success I decided to make my own simple graph without redundant functionality.

Comment: yes, you are right. if you try you can do that. All the best. but i have second opinion so i provided this link of my answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for Your suggestions.I got the exact output by using Stacked Barchart in Mpchart Library